# Force Quit (Ctl + Alt + Del)

Tags: system, apps

I was wondering if there is a hotkey for terminating a program in Elm. OS. I want to recommend this OS to people who have 0 knowledge on computers. I have had several apps freeze and no force quit diag. If there is NOT I would recommend adding some kind of key combo. If there is, can someone let me know what it is? There is also nothing in the help documentation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is not a default app or keybinding for killing a process. Out of the box the easiest thing you can do is press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and execute the `xkill` command and then click whatever window you wish to kill.

Seperate from that there is a really nice [Monitor](https://github.com/stsdc/monitor) app by Stanisław Dac in the AppCenter:

[image: Screenshot of the Monitor app]

Also see https://askubuntu.com/a/95202/672975 for more severe options that still allow for a graceful shutdown/reboot of GUI or entire system.

Comment: Thank you for the info; Sounds like the easiest link to do is install the monitor app you talking about. Looks very similar to the mac Activity Monitor. This seems best for people who don't have a lot of computer knowledge, which would be my use case for this OS